# Probability of picking an item x from a pool within n tries, where we remove non-x items from the pool on each try?

Tags: probability

For example, let's say I want to draw a blue ball. I have a pool of $99$ red balls and $1$ blue ball. I take balls out from the pool one by one. If I have a red ball, I throw it into my neighbor's backyard, thus removing it from the pool. What is the probability that I draw the blue ball within at most $10$ tries?

The probability of drawing the blue ball on the first try is $\frac{1}{100}$, on the second try it's $\frac1{99}$, and so on. But I don't think the answer is simply $\frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{99}  + ... \frac{1}{90} $, because the probability of *not* drawing the blue ball on a given trial has some influence. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Note a second try will *only* occur if the first try is unsuccessful, i.e., a red ball is drawn instead of the blue one.

Comment: Your nieghbor has a very happy dog. Aside from that, if you took ten balls all at once, what is the probability that the blue ball is among them?

Comment: @DanielMathias Embarassingly enough, I'm not sure of that either...all I know is that it involves using the "choose" operator, maybe?

Comment: No, it is simply $\frac{10}{100}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to look at it:

Instead of tossing out the red balls and instead of stopping when you reach the blue ball, suppose as you pulled the balls out, you simply put them in a row. You will wind up with a row of balls where 99 of them are red and 1 is blue. Your problem is equivalent to the blue ball being among the first ten balls. There is a $\dfrac{1}{100}$ chance that a particular slot will contain a blue ball. It is impossible for two slots to contain the blue ball, so the probabilities are disjoint and therefore additive. Thus, as @DanielMathias said, the probability that the blue ball resides among the first ten balls drawn is $\dfrac{10}{100}$.